# The Demo example of RocketMQ in .NET SDK throwing System.TypeInitializationException exception

Tags: rocketmq

I am running the Demo Example given for .NET SDK RocketMQ. https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/29561.html?spm=5176.doc29561.3.3.nIAzgT

But it is throwing the below  exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' 

Additional information: The type initializer for 'ons.ONSClient4CPPPINVOKE' threw an exception.
```

I am not getting any solution for the issue.Can anyone please give a solution for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ONSClient4CPP.dll and ONSClient4CPP.lib in bin folder and vc++ 2015 is installed.